# Right to left offset formula with match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset, right-to-left

I'm looking to return the start and end dates of a person availability based upon a gantt chart of their hours on a project.

I can at the minute only return the start of their availability, essentially my formula is looking left to right and returning the date of the first "0" cell it meets.

I need the formula to look right to left and return the date of the cell of the last "0" it meets.

Formula currently is: 
    `=IFERROR(OFFSET(B3,(ROW(B3)-2)*-1,MATCH(0,C3:O3,0)),"")`

[image: Data is available here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using the formula above and the link provided. My data set was different to the sample one shown. Hence the cell references are different.

```
=(OFFSET(A3,(ROW(A3)-2)*-1,LOOKUP(9.999999999999E+307,IF(AA3:CP3>0,COLUMN(AA3:CP3)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula will return the results you're after:
`{=INDEX($C$2:$S4,1,MAX(IF($C4:$S4>0,COLUMN($C4:$S4),0)))}`

Enter as an array/CSE formula (use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to complete the formula - this will put the curly brackets in).

NB:  It will return 00/01/1900 if the last date is greater than 0.
Adding this custom format to the result cells will hide the 00/01/1900: `dd/mm/yyyy;;;`

I used this to reference to get the answer:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/234469-find-last-value-row-greater-than-zero.html